# "The PluginDescriptor not found" error when executing copy-resources maven-resources-plugin's goal

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

As part of my pom.xml I copy some extra resources to the target directory as follows.

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>copy-package-doc</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/package/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/doc</outputDirectory>
     <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>doc</nonFilteredFileExtension>
     </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
     <resources>
      <resource>
       <directory>doc</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
       <includes>
        <include>**/*.doc</include>
       </includes>
       <excludes>
        <exclude>**/~*.doc</exclude>
       </excludes>
      </resource>
     </resources>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
   <execution>
    <id>copy-package-config</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/package/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
     <resources>
      <resource>
       <directory>config</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
     </resources>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
```

When I package artifact I get error:

```
The PluginDescriptor for the plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin was not found. Should have been in realm: ClassRealm[/plugins/org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1@48/thread:Worker-17, parent: null]
```

How to fix that? Why I get this error?

Thanks,
Rafal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched from Q for Eclipse to M2Eclipse and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Include info on version used for: eclipse, java, maven

Try running `mvn package -U -e` and include output on pastebin.

Also try using another version of resources-plugin `<version>2.3</version>` or why do you need `2.4.1`

---

Sounds like you got a corrupted maven plugin

Try deleting the folder `maven-resources-plugin` contained in `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven`

Or post (or include link to) whole error message

Comment: Switch to version 2.3 is not valid solution in my case. I had tried this before I posted question to StackOverflow. I cannot check "mvn package -U -e" because problem do not exist since I have moved to M2Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen lots of similar issues on the web (e.g. in [IDEA-16866](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-16866), [IDEADEV-24376](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEADEV-24376), [MIDEA-109](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MIDEA-109) or this one about [Eclipse/IAM](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=6873&S=fa694d7c17fefcf1fd04a336f7c53e14) which seems to be the closest). In all cases, this seems related to Maven Embedder.

I have actually no idea of the cause of the problem and have no better suggestion than to use the latest version of maven (2.2.1) if it's not the case and/or to try with previous versions of the maven-resources-plugin (2.3) to verify that this is not a regression.

If this doesn't work, go the [Maven 2.x Resources Plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES) Jira and open an issue.